# Deploy Flexipage Assignments

Tags: lightning, deployment, metadata

I can deploy a flexipage using the *flexipage metadata type*. But I can't seem to find anywhere the *flexipage assignments type*. How can flexipage assignments be deployed?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Flexipage Assignments are called ProfileOverride. It is documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_profileactionoverride.htm)

The metadata looks like the one below, it is a part of a **Custom App**:

```
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
<profileActionOverrides>
    <actionName>View</actionName>
    <content>CustomObjectFlexiPage</content>
    <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
    <pageOrSobjectType>TestObj__c</pageOrSobjectType>
    <type>Flexipage</type>
    <profile>standard</profile>
    <recordType>TestObj__c.TestRecordType</recordType>
</profileActionOverrides>
<defaultLandingTab>standard-home</defaultLandingTab>
<formFactors>Large</formFactors>
<label>My Custom App</label>
<tab>standard-Account</tab>
<tab>standard-Opportunity</tab>
<uiType>Lightning</uiType>
<navType>Standard</navType>
```

And the package.xml would look like the one below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
 <types>
    <members>MyCustomApp</members>
    <name>CustomApplication</name>
  </types>
 <version>39.0</version>
 </Package>
```

Comment: Its like we have to retrieve all/most of the applications to get ProfileActionOverrides.