# Assigning Lightning record page using metadata api

Tags: apex, flexipages, lightning-record-page

After creating a lightning record type, when we are trying to assign the Lightning record page to record types using the activation button, it throws an error - "there are too many assignments on this page layout. Use metadata api for assignment " (attached screenshot)[image]

Could anyone please help regarding how to fix this error using Metadata Apis
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check this answer https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/204674/deploy-flexipage-assignments